# How to build a package in an existing directory with RStudio

Tags: r, build, rstudio

I am working on a making a package in RStudio. I already have it as a project, and I am using Git for version control.  My directory structure is currently

```
--Project
   --R
   --.git
```

With the R code in the `R` directory.

My problem occurs when I go to build the package. I want to call the package "Project" and I get the a directory structure like this:

```
--Project
   --R
   --.git
   --Project
      --man
      --R
```

And in this setup there are two sets of R files, on in each "R" directory. The less nested one is being versioned by Git, the more nested one is the source for the package. Is there some way to get the package to just use the preexisting "R" directory? Can I just reanme my current "Project" directory to something else, make the package as "Project" and then copy the .git directory to the new Project directory?

Comment: Can you create a new project in rstudio and create the Project directory under Project? Then, create the r package as normal. I've never had good luck renaming things after the fact but maybe that's just me

Comment: @rawr I could do that. The only problem is that then I have one R directory that git is tacking and a second that is used for the build. I may just rename `Project` to `Project 2` and then build a new `Project` directory and try to copy over the .git stuff.

Comment: I do that but use a one for git and the second as a dev version. Probably not ideal but it works for me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In RStudio (I'm using v. 1.0.136), this can be done via the menu options *Tools > Project Options > Build Tools*. Select *Package* from the drop-down list for *Project build tools*, and if you know what you're doing, fill in any of the other fields as you deem appropriate.

This operation is not going to necessarily give you the structure above i.e. `man` and `R` folders or a `DESCRIPTION` file, which can be done with the `use_description()` function from the `usethis` package.